# Why Raman Scattering is inelastic scattering?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

I have read about Raman scattering but I did not understand inelastic nature of this scattering. Can somebody explain it clearly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energies of the incident and the scattered photons are different, i.e. a part of the kinetic energy of the photon is transmitted into the internal energy of the atom or vice-versa:
$$\hbar\omega_{incident} = \hbar\Omega_{atom} +\hbar\omega_{scattered}.$$

**Remark:**
In response to the comments, some clarifications are in order:

- The *total energy (of the system)* is always conserved in collisions.
- What is conserved in *elastic collisions* is the mechanical energy of the system, while in *inelastic collisions* part of this energy is converted into the *internal energy*.
- $E_{total} = E_{mechanical} + E_{internal}$

Comment: But when 2 Bodies collide elastically, isn't the energy of both bodies changed either ? So what's the evidence Raman scattering is inelastic? Respectively what tells me that the total energy is changed? To me Raman scattering also looks like  elastic scattering where the Bodies just exchange energy.

Comment: @Leon *total energy* is always conserved. What is conserved in elastic collisions is the *mechanical energy of the system*, while in inelastic collisions part of this energy is converted into the *internal energy*. *Total energy = mechanical energy + internal energy*

Answer (score 0):

A rough short answer is, that the frequency is changed after the scattering by picking up/"loosing" energy to the scattering object.

For example when approaching the surface of a solid, it can induce surface phonons or "pick one up" therefore changing its energy = frequency after the scattering process.

Experimentally you can then pick up a Stokes- and Antistokes- peak around the elastic Rayleigh-Peak.

Is this the answer you are looking for? Or is more in-depth needed?